# Entity Framework Core lexical comparison

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

In SQL, it's easy to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ATable
    WHERE (Column1, Column2) < (10, 23)
```

Can I do something similar with Entity Framework Core? And will it utilize proper SQL query or will it filter in-memory, which is unusable for any larger table?

The only thing that comes to my mind is coding the comparison explicitly, which is ugly even for just two columns.

**EDIT:** Badly optimized version, don't use.

```
context.ATable.Where(t => t.Column1 < 10 || t.Column1 == 10 && t.Column2 < 23);
```

Comment: "WHERE (Column1, Column2) < (10, 23)" is it Sql server ?

Comment: @Stormcloak Specifically, SQLite. But isn't it pretty common in other database engines as well? That's why I didn't specify. I'm pretty sure at least PostgreSQL supports it.

Comment: I am sure about that the sql server doesn't support it.

Comment: @Stormcloak Interesting. I consider it a very useful feature for pagination so I must say I'm surprised. I never actually had more than a causal encounter with SQL server so I didn't know. I assume this isn't high on the list of priorities for the EFC team, then.

Answer (score 1):

After [researching a bit more](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page), this row value comparison feature *is* in the SQL standard, but most RDBMS' never implemented them properly. So I don't expect it to be implemented in LINQ soon, and especially not in EF Core.

Workarounds are not pretty. Here are some logically equivalent LINQ examples.

```
// *Do not use.*
// Simplest logic, but the database engines have issues in realising that
// there is actually an implied "t.Column1 <= 10".
ATable.Where(t => t.Column1 < 10 ||
                  t.Column1 == 10 && t.Column2 < 23);

// Markus Winand's style. Confusing, IMO.
ATable.Where(t => t.Column1 <= 10 &&
                  !(t.Column1 == 10 && t.Column2 >= 23));

// My personal favourite.
ATable.Where(t => t.Column1 <= 10 &&
                  (t.Column1 < 10 || t.Column2 < 23));
```